# Is it possible to Perform a find in Excel using ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, closedxml

Is it possible to do a find in ClosedXML? I looked through their documentation and there is no record of it.  How else can I look at all the methods included in ClosedXML, so I can find some of these things on my own?

Comment: You can search using `string` methods if you can read content from the Excel (I didn't use ClosedXML).

Comment: @KernelMode, Yeah I can do that with a loop but that will take much longer.  I was hoping I did not have to.

Comment: can you give a concrete example what you're after?  It looks like this link should get you going in the right direction: https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Better-lambdas

Comment: @KernelMode, That is looking inside an individual cell for a string.  I want to look at multiple cells to see if the string exists in any of them.

Answer (score 6):

The link given by [sous2817](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422305/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-find-in-excel-using-closedxml#comment71991132_42422305) shows the right way in ClosedXML. Something like this:

```
sheet.CellsUsed(cell => cell.GetValue<string>() == searchstring)
```

or

```
sheet.CellsUsed(cell => cell.GetValue<string>().Contains(searchstring))
```

And yes, this is a relatively expensive operation for large sheets.